# References for linear advection system with constant coefficients

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, matlab, finite-differences, hyperbolic-equations

I'm searching for references where I can found the study of finite difference schemes for linear advection system with constant coefficients.
More specifically, I would like to read about:
The Symbol, Phase and Amplitude Errors, dissipation and dispersion, and some MATLAB examples

Thanks you a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested by Chap. 3 of the book [1]:

> **3 Finite Difference Methods for Hyperbolic Equations**
>
> 3.1 Introduction
> 3.2 Some basic difference schemes
> 3.3 Dissipation and dispersion errors
> 3.4 Extensions to conservation laws
> 3.5 The second-order hyperbolic PDEs
> 3.6 Numerical examples with MATLAB codes
> 3.7 Bibliographical remarks
> 3.8 Exercises

Besides the absence of Matlab examples, you might also enjoy Chap. 5 of the monograph [2] which includes many exercises & detailed examples.

[1] J. Li, Y.-T. Chen: [*Computational Partial Differential Equations Using MATLAB®*](http://books.google.com/books?id=xias6cGNHA4C), 2nd ed., [Chapman & Hall/CRC](https://www.routledge.com/Computational-Partial-Differential-Equations-Using-MATLAB/Li-Chen/p/book/9780367217747), 2020.

[2] J.C. Strikwerda: [*Finite Difference Schemes and Partial Differential Equations*](https://books.google.com/books?id=mbdt5XT25AsC), 2nd ed., [SIAM](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898717938), 2004.

Comment: Thank you a lot for sharing this two nice books, I'm sure  I can learn a lot from them. After a first look, I only saw the second reference discuss the stability (amplification matrix) of a system of PDEs, and the other reference, as you mention, define the properties that I ask for in the scalar case...

Comment: @Almendrof66 Then it should do the job, as the properties of the system can be deduced from the scalar case by diagonalization (see also LeVeque as well as Godlewski & Raviart in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2364307/418542)).